Why does the function still minus my dictionary
So, ive been doing my python project for some time, got a big problem about a func
https://pastebin.com/u6ZHXbxc
this function converts goes through each 'e'type in price and checks if its more points in POINTS dict (or if its equal)
however, if its less, it tries to find if theres a bigger 'e' type in points that has atleast 1 point, and then it converts it from 1 to 1000, from 'e'type to 'e'type-3.
it then checks if successful actions are equal to the points len and then if its true, send the new points and when false - False (bool)
when i try this function with these lines of code:
points = {"e0":101, "e3":0}
price = {"e0":1, "e3":2}
print(buycheck(points, price), points)

it makes something with the points dict and somehow changes it, even though i dont ask to return the new points dict
**also i understood now that somehow python changes all the dicts even if theyre copies of another, it changes like every dict in this func, both the original one and the copy
how can i change it, or what i should with my func (there are some problems left with buycheck (for example:
points = {"e0":101, "e3":1}
price = {"e0":1, "e3":2}

it gives -2 in the dict), but i think ill try to fix them by myself. ?**
i tried changing the return func, but it still doesnt work

(first: you should post all the relevant code in the question, not pastebin) ...you are modifying the dicts inside buycheck function. The code inside the function receives the actual dicts you pass in as arguments, not a copy of them.

The dict is passed by reference to the function, so any change you make to it inside the function, which you are, is reflected in the original too. If you truly want to copy, consider using points.copy() or deepcopy(points)

It's not passed by reference, because assignments to the parameter do not affect the value passed. Python is neither call-by-value nor call-by-reference, but something in between. https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html is a good reference on the behavior of Python names.

Python dicts are passed by reference. When you pass it to a function and the function changes it, the function is changing the only copy of the dictionary you have.
If you do want to make a copy, you'll have to explicitly make a copy.

from copy import copy

def buycheck(points, price): 
    lpoints = copy(points)
    price = copy(price)


Note that while copy works for simple dictionaries like in the code you've put into your question, for more complex, nested dictionaries, you may need to use copy.deepcopy instead of the copy.copy used here.
Also note that I haven't seen your pastebin link, so I don't know whether you need copies of both args. In general, only make copies when you need a copy which you're going to modify. Avoid making too many copies, especially in deeply nested loops or recursive functions or so.

Nothing in Python is ever passed by reference, and the type of the object doesn't affect the evaluation strategy, and there is only one evaluation strategy (which again, is not call by reference, or call by value for that matter)

Thanks! FIgured out how to do this, now everything works

I'm curious, what is one use case a beginner to intermediate python programmer might come across where the semantic of passed-by-reference fails, even if what's happening under the hood is different? Even though I've known the implementation is different for years, using the mental shorthand of passed by reference is yet to fail me.

@juanpa.arrivillaga I'd argue that passing mutable types like lists and dicts (like in this case) is passing by reference. Both the function and the outer scope share reference to the same object. This special case can be confusing to beginners.

All values are passed the same way. The only difference is that lists and dicts have methods that allow you to mutate the object which things like ints and strs lack.

@ChintalagiriShashank I don't know what to tell you, but it is simply the incorrect term. Call by reference would work like this: def foo(&x): x = [] then y = [1,2,3]; foo(y); print(y) would print []. i.e. assignment to the parameter would  function the the same as assigning to the variable in the scope of the caller). That isn't how Python works.

@mhenning there is no special case and passing any object works exactly the same way. This is very simple to understand and explain, and people get confused when you (incorrectly) say there is some speial case going on. Note, "mutability" just means that the public interface doesn't expose mutator methods. You can still mutate an int object, for example, if you know the implementation details, and you'll see, the evaluation strategy works exactly the same way for int objects.

The proble fundamentally is that a lot of educational materials were written as if the only two evaluation strategies that exist are "call by reference" or "call by value" (probably because you were only learning Fortran or C). But that is a false dichotomy. And again, python supports neither.

Here is a classic way to tell if your language supports call by reference, can you write a def swap(a, b) function that works like this: x = 1; y = 2; swap(x, y); print(x, y) will print 2 1. You can't do that in Python.

often nowadays the terms "by reference" and "by value" are just vaguely used to imply something like "modifications inside the function will or will not affect a variable outside the function". Probably the worst thing that has occurred is the common Javaism of saying "call by value where the value is a reference". Which is the same as Python. But this evaluation strategy is actually named "called by sharing"  which is a very academic term (you see "call by assignment" in python circles as well)

I like the term "call by object".

The thing ive done is to put in your func result variable COPIED dicts (prb works with lists too), then simply work with these func variables, and after that if everythings ok return a copied dict, else return your original dict
